Not able to use axios in stapi custom plugin V4
I am trying to build custom plugin using strapi v4.
I am fetching the data using endpoint /${pluginId}/games and if I use request from @strapi/helper-plugin then it works as expected but if I try to do the same using axios then it giving me 401.
I am not using the request because it has been deprecated and they have added useFetchClient hook which I will not be able to use in the saga file. I am looking for any workaround which allows me to fetch the data without using deprecated requests from the saga file.
function* getLobbiesSaga() {
  try {
    const response = yield request(`/${pluginId}/lobbies`); //works
    const response = yield axios.get(`/${pluginId}/lobbies`); //returns 401

    if (response.data) {
      yield put(getLobbiesSuccess(response.data));
    } else {
      throw new Error("Lobbies couldn't be fetched");
    }
  } catch (error) {
    yield put(getLobbiesFailure(error));
  }
}

I have checked the strapi documentation and I can see that axios is there but the documentation is for strapi v5 and I am using the strapi v4. So, I am not sure if strapi does not support in v4 or I am missing somethins.

